# Invalid combination of button flags MOUSE 5 BUTTONS

Tags: java, mouse

I have a mouse with 5 buttons, but if I put:

```
robot.mousePress (5);
robot.mouseRelease (5);
```

This error tells me:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination of button flags
```

However, when I check `java.awt.MouseInfo.getNumberOfButtons` it returns 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument that you have to pass to `mousePress` and `mouseRelease` isn't just the number of the button.  It's usually a power of two - or maybe the sum of a few powers of  two, if you're trying to press multiple buttons at once.

The best way to find the right power of two for any particular button is with `InputEvent.getMaskForButton()`, where you pass in a number from 1 up to the number of buttons.  So in your case, you need

```
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.getMaskForButton(5));
```